# namespaces in SOAPpy not working as expected

Tags: python, soap, soappy, axis2c

I'm having an issue correctly interfacing with a SOAP API running on Axis2:

What happens is I should call the login method with two arguments (loginName and password) and it returns an authentication token that I will use for subsequent interaction.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy

s_user = 'Administrator'
s_pass = 'securityThroughObscurity'
s_host = '192.168.76.130:8998'

namespace = 'http://bcc.inc.com/IncSecurity'
url = 'http://' + s_host + '/axis2/services/IncSecurityService'

DHCPServ = SOAPProxy(url, namespace)
DHCPServ.config.dumpSOAPOut = 1
DHCPServ.config.dumpSOAPIn = 1
DHCPResp = DHCPServ.login(loginName=s_user, password=s_pass)
```

The Axis2 server on the other side returns an XML error stating `Data element of the OM Node is NULL`.  Looking at the Axis2 logs, I see the error is `adb_login.c(383) non nillable or minOuccrs != 0 element loginName missing`

I then packet captured the `login` XML from a known working Java client versus the XML from this client and these are the differences between the two:

SOAPpy:

```
<ns1:login xmlns:ns1="http://bcc.inc.com/IncSecurity" SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<password xsi:type="xsd:string">securityThroughObscurity</password>
<loginName xsi:type="xsd:string">Administrator</loginName>
</ns1:login>
```

Java:

```
<ns2:login xmlns:ns2="http://bcc.inc.com/IncSecurity">
<ns2:loginName>Administrator</ns2:loginName>
<ns2:password>securityThroughObscurity</ns2:password>
</ns2:login>
```

So this means that for some reason (probably related to my lack of knowledge in Python and SOAPpy) the namespace is not being applied to the variables being used in the `login` method, so by all accounts they don't actually exist and the error is warranted.

Also, it seems to be flipping the variables around and putting the password before loginName but I don't think that matters much.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a known bug in SOAPPy, someone has suggested a simple patch: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=523083

Alternately (assuming you have access to the service WSDL), SOAPPy lets you specify a WSDL instead of just a namespace. This looks like it will provide better namespace information to the envelope generation code. http://diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/introspection.html

Finally, if SOAPPy just isn't working for you, try [Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) (it's [better documented](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) than SOAPPy).

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
client = Client(WSDL_LOCATION)
guid = client.service.someFunctionName("a string argument", 42)
```

Good luck!

Comment: in your example if someFuncitonName has a point in it, how did you solve it? For example : guid = client.service.some.FunctionName("a string argument", 42)